# TypeError: Cannot read property '_alreadyWrapped' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ethereum, truffle

I created a project that integrates the truffle and react frameworks，Then I configured rinkeby test network of Ethereum  in truffle-config.js.But, when I migrate the contract to rinkeby network, something went wrong.

```
truffle compile    
truffle migrate  --network rinkeby
```

Then came some mistakes

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '_alreadyWrapped' of undefined
    at Object.wrap (C:\Users\Lsy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\wrapper.js:13:1)
    at Object.wrap (C:\Users\Lsy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\index.js:9:1)
    at Object.create (C:\Users\Lsy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\provider\index.js:14:1)
    at TruffleConfig.get [as provider] (C:\Users\Lsy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\config\dist\configDefa
ults.js:189:1)
    at Object.detect (C:\Users\Lsy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\environment\environment.js:19:1)
    at C:\Users\Lsy\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate.js:192:1
Truffle v5.1.1 (core: 5.1.1)
Node v12.13.0
```

The Project directory is shown below：

[image]

truffle-config.js

```
 const path = require("path");
    const HDWalletProvider = require('@truffle/hdwallet-provider');
    const fs = require('fs')  

    let secrets;
    console.log(path.join(__dirname, "secrets.json"));

    if (fs.existsSync(path.join(__dirname, "secrets.json"))){
      secrets = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "secrets.json"),'utf8'));
    }else{
      console.log("secrets.json doesn't exist!")
    }

    module.exports = {
      contracts_build_directory: path.join(__dirname, "client/src/contracts"),
      networks: {
        ganache:{
          host:"127.0.0.1",
          port:7545,
          network_id:"*"
        },
        develop: {
          port: 8545
        },
        rinkeby:{
          provider:()=>{
            new HDWalletProvider(secrets.mnemonic,"https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/"+secrets.infuraProjectId);
          },
          network_id: '4'
        }
      }
    };
```

This problem has been bothering me for a long time, who can help me! Really Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot the return statement:

```js
rinkeby: {
  provider: () => {
    return new HDWalletProvider(secrets.mnemonic,"https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/"+secrets.infuraProjectId);
  },
  network_id: 4
}
```

Comment: Yes,you are right. I'm  so careless. Thanks very much!

Comment: In addition, I change `network_id:'4'` to `network_id:4`.